# Stop CollectionView to create new Buttons while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I've got a question. I have a button inside a CollectionView Cell, which moves when it get touched for the first time. Here is the "moving" code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(80,112,30,20);
}];
```

But when I scroll down and scroll up again, there is the same button created again on its old place, how can I fix it? The button which moved is still there -> the button is twice in the cell.
Here is how the button is created:

```
-(UIButton *)button{
    _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(111,112,30,20);
    [_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [_button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(decMethod)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return _button;
}
```

and here the CollectionView Cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView           cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell *cell =
    (CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell *)[collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell addSubview:cell.buttonInc];


return cell;
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UICollection will kill the cells not offscreen when needed for the performance. In your situation, you may create an NSMutableArray to record all cells moving history. If one cell has already moved, then set YES to the corresponding index of array. before you animate your button , just check the array to find if it has been moved.

Comment: It doesn't work, the CollectionView still adds randomly a new button on its first position

Comment: cause the collectionView will reuse the cell automatically for the performance concern. if you don't want the button after the first time, just check the cell's contentView's subview, if there is a button, then remove it